# Strange time parsing

Tags: parsing, go, time

Simple code:

```
func main() {
    date := "2020-12-23T16:39:24.362+06:00"
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000+06:00", date)
    fmt.Printf("t = %s", t)
}
```

Result is `t = 2006-12-23 16:39:24.362 +0000 UTC`

Link to playground: https://play.golang.org/p/3U6CzIrrMsM

Where I made a mistake?

Comment: You can use a predefined format; `t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, date)` - [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference time has `-0700` time zone. Quoting from [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents. The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
> ```
>
> would be interpreted if it were the value; it serves as an example of the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the input string.

With this change it works:

```
date := "2020-12-23T16:39:24.362+06:00"

t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00", date)
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Printf("t = %s", t)
```

And outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XJuyHgKyTp5)):

```
<nil>
t = 2020-12-23 16:39:24.362 +0600 +0600
```